# Convert XML Document to Dictionary

Tags: xml, c++-cli

Using C++/Cli in .NET 4.0 (VS2010), I want to convert an XML document to a dictionary.  The document looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Created 26-04-2013 09:05 -->
<DEVICE_CONFIG>
    <ALL
        username="bob"
        features="all"
    />
</DEVICE_CONFIG>
```

I just care about the values in <ALL ... />, which is a series of pairs:

> key="value"

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more sample input? With just this, it's hard to tell what is a constant tag that can be expected & relied on, and what is variable data that needs to be ignored.

Comment: Is this better?  The input I provided is the entire file, except for all the key-value pairs.  I expect around 30 key-value pairs per file.

Comment: I was asking for more key-value pairs. With just the data you've shown, it's not obvious what's a key, what's a value, and what's junk to not include in the output. Are you expecting the dictionary to contain "username=bob", "features=all", not "bob=all"?

Comment: The key is the token on the left of the '=', the value is on the right.  Keys will be made up of digits, letters and '.'s. Value will also include other symbols, e.g. urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String^ s = 
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n" + 
    "<!-- Created 26-04-2013 09:05 -->\r\n" + 
    "<DEVICE_CONFIG>\r\n" + 
    "    <ALL\r\n" + 
    "        username=\"bob\"\r\n" + 
    "        features=\"all\"\r\n" + 
    "    />\r\n" + 
    "</DEVICE_CONFIG>";

XElement^ root = XElement::Parse(s);

// The DEVICE_CONFIG node is boring. Skip to the "ALL" node.
XElement^ allNode = dynamic_cast<XElement^>(root->FirstNode);

Dictionary<String^, String^>^ results = gcnew Dictionary<String^, String^>();
for each(XAttribute^ attribute in allNode->Attributes())
{
    results->Add(attribute->Name->ToString(), attribute->Value);
}
```

I'm just skipping to the inner element of whatever the root is. You could find the "ALL" node in other ways: iterate until you find an XElement that [HasAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.hasattributes.aspx), you could search for "ALL" by [name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx), etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I needed to add a reference to System::Xml::Linq in the project, and now it builds okay.